# How to use a variable in a regular expression in nginx?

Tags: nginx, configuration, regex

I've spent some time trying to find the answer before writing this question:

I have several `location` blocks in my nginx config file that look like this:

```
location ~ ^/(doc|img|bla|foo)/metadata/$ { ... }

location ~ ^/(doc|img|bla|foo)/deleted/$ { ... }

location ~ ^/(doc|img|bla|foo)/something/$ { ... }
```

So I thought it would be a good idea to refactor the repeated regular expression into a variable that I set in the `server` section (also because I know I'll have to add to it in the future), like so:

```
server {
     set $my_regex doc|img|blah|foo;

     # I also tried this one:
     set $my_regex "doc|img|blah|foo";
     ....
}
```

Which I would then reuse inside the location blocks:

```
# this doesn't have any effect
location ~ ^/($my_regex)/metadata/$ { ... }

# this one neither
location ~ ^/(\$my_regex)/deleted/$ { ... }

# and this one neither
location ~ ^/(${my_regex})/something/$ { ... }
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Greetings! Just interesting: did You try to combine two expressions in one?  
`location ~ ^/(doc|img|bla|foo)/(metadata|deleted|something)/$ { ... }`

Comment: @SergeySerov No, I'm not going that far. I'm just trying to refactor the regular expression that has been used three times by assigning it to a variable that I then would like to use in the `location` directive.

Comment: @SergeySerov Actually I now have combined them into one, and use a `rewrite`. But that doesn't solve the initial problem. :-)

Comment: Now You have one line instead three, this is good already. Yes, the task with string variable not resolved yet. It is interesting task for me too ;)

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to use variables in `location` matching.

If you want it, you probably doing something wrong. In this case you could try nesting locations.

Comment: @AlexeyTan I've reduced the use of the regex to only two occurrences which will make the pain of maintaining somewhat more bearable. But I guess I have to find another solution, maybe scripting?

Answer (score 0):

Please check at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13706658/variable-capture-in-nginx-location-matching) as they said in NGINX [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names)

```
The PCRE library supports named captures using the following syntax:

?<name> Perl 5.10 compatible syntax, supported since PCRE-7.0
?'name' Perl 5.10 compatible syntax, supported since PCRE-7.0
?P<name>    Python compatible syntax, supported since PCRE-4.0
```

*Named captures are a feature of PCRE and they have different syntax 
available in different versions. For the syntax you use ? you must have PCRE 7.0 at least.*

Comment: I don't think I'm looking for named captures. From what I understand, named captures allow to reference a matched part of a regex by name rather than by a numeric index in later processing.  Here however I'm looking for the possibility to reuse an existing variable inside a regex. Maybe that's just not possible?