# How to use a variable in place of a regex

Tags: nginx

I want to use a variable in a regex. Like,

```
set $valid_host_regex ...

if ($host !~ ((^$)|($valid_host_regex))) {
   return 404;
}
```

It seems it is not possible to use a variable name in regex string. 
[How to use a variable in a regular expression in nginx?](https://serverfault.com/questions/898065/how-to-use-a-variable-in-a-regular-expression-in-nginx)

So, I tried using complete regex as a variable

```
set $valid_host_regex ((^$)|(...))

if ($host !~ $valid_host_regex) {
   return 404;
}
```

But this is also not working. Am I doing something wrong, or is it just not possible to use a variable in place of regex? I am not able to find any documentation or answer for this anywhere.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It’s not possible. And you’re doing something wrong. What problem do you want to solve?

Comment: You either should use separate server blocks or use regexp in server_name directive.